# How can I share my clipboard across my devices?

Tags: chrome, cross-platform, clipboard

I'm looking for an mobile app with an accompanying cross-platform desktop companion (or Chrome extension) to allow the sharing of clipboard contents across a range of devices.

Right now, to transfer short bits of text (e.g. URLs) from one device to another, I use [Pushbullet](http://pushbullet.com). This is a workable solution, but **I'm looking for something a bit more seamless, so I can <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> a URL on my Android device and paste it into the address bar on my [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) machine**. In short, I want a unified clipboard that's shared across devices.

More platforms are definitely preferred because I often use a range of devices that run [Chrome OS](http://www.google.com/chromebook), Xubuntu, Windows, OSX, Android, iOS amongst others. It's going to be difficult to find a solution that works across all, so something that works across 3 of them or works on mobile as well as Google Chrome is fine.

Holroy has graciously pointed out below that Pushbullet [actually supports this](https://blog.pushbullet.com/2014/11/20/cross-device-copy-and-paste-for-all/), and I can confirm it works brilliantly once you enable it for each of your devices.

Comment: Have you considered Google Keep? It will introduce some extra steps, but in return it works almost straight out of the box. To get copy&paste across devices would require some coordination or tool installment on both host and client, and with multiple devices that might be cumbersome.

Comment: Pushbullet allows sharing in a similar way to Google Keep. I understand I can manually copy and paste into Keep to have a sort of online keyboard but I'm looking for a more seamless experience. Also, Keep seems to mangle code spacing and indentation.

Comment: Doesn't pushbullet already support [this](https://blog.pushbullet.com/2014/11/20/cross-device-copy-and-paste-for-all/)? What is lacking in their solution?

Comment: Oops, I must have missed the announcement. I just checked the Pushbullet options and found it unchecked. Enabled it now and it works great! Feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the newer versions of Pushbullet already has [universal copy and paste](https://blog.pushbullet.com/2014/11/20/cross-device-copy-and-paste-for-all/), so try enabling it in the preferences, or possibly update app if you have a really old installation.

[image: mobile]
[image: chrome]